# how to change size of point in ChartJS

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I'd like to change a size of the point in my chart.
[image]

The point should be as small as possible. Was trying to use

```
pointHoverRadius: 1
```

But it doesn't work.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: have you tried to use like pointHoverRadius: 0.1 ?

Comment: please provide your code

Comment: besides, the property only works on the hover event , you should check out the document.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

You would have to set the **`pointRadius`** property to **`1`** as well *(so the point becomes small initially)*, along with the **`pointHoverRadius`** *(remains small on hover)*

```
pointRadius: 1,
pointHoverRadius: 1
```

Comment: An improvement to this answer would be to say where this goes.  I'm assuming in the corresponding dataset, and I'll try that, but it would be a much better answer if it included this info already.

Comment: The same can be set globally as
`options.elements.point.radius` and `options.elements.point.hoverRadius`

Answer (score 33):

It indeed needs to go in the dataset, like so:

```
{
    type: 'scatter',
    data: {
        labels: ['2015', '2016', '2017', '2018', '2019', '2020'],
        datasets: [
            {
                label: 'Cars',
                data: [{x:-10,y:0}, {x:0,y:10}, {x:10,y:5}, {x:4,y:8}],
                pointRadius: 10,
                ....
            },
            {
                label: 'Bikes',
                data: [{x:10,y:3}, {x:-2,y:6}, {x:9,y:3}, {x:11,y:6}],
                pointRadius: 10,
                ...
            }
        ]
    },
    options: {
       ...
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

In [ChartJS documentation](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/elements.html#point-configuration) it instructs us to edit `options.elements.point` object for customizing how point looks.

There are two fields that might be of interest for this question:

- `radius` how big should point generally be (you probably want this one)
- `hoverRadius` how big should point be when user hovers on it

So final example of `options` object would be (skipping unrelated properties):

```
const options = {
  elements: {
    point: {
      radius: 1,
      hoverRadius: 2, // ex.: to make it bigger when user hovers put larger number than radius.
    }
  }
}
```